# How to react on binded object in the link function of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my web project I am writing a directive which has to react on data I get from a server. The directive has to be as generic as possible which is the reason I am getting my data via a controller. The next code is a simplified pseudo example as I hope it should work:

first my controller:

```
AnApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.theObject = {};

    $scope.initialize = function(){
        $http.get("url").success(function(returnObject){
            $scope.theObject = returnObject;
        });
    };
});
```

the directive:

```
AnApp.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            theObject: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            //What do I have to do here to read my attributes when they change in the controller?
        }
});
```

And the html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <div data-my-directive="" data-the-object="theObject"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is when something changes on theObject, a reaction on the change happens in the link function. So far I tried it with $parse, $observe, scope.$watch but none worked. They all gave back either the string "theObject" or undefined. How do I reach the object or array when it has been retrieved from the server and been put on the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-way `=` (instead of `@`) binding is probably suited for your purpose, changes to the model can be watched that way. When you use `@` it actually binds the text as is, for which you may have to bind it as `{{theObject}}` and watch for changes (but you may have to parse the JSON to object back).

```
AnApp.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            theObject: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          var unwatcher =  scope.$watch('theObject', function(v){
                 if(angular.isDefined(v)){
                          unwatcher(); //May be unwatch if you do not want to watch it anymore. 
                        //got the value do something
                 }
                 //This will react to changes now.
            });
        }
});
```

And if it is just one time initialization that you need then:- you can remove the watch once is it is initialized...

Comment: Thank you. The change to the = made the scope.$watch work. I thought the @ was a oneway binding and that is why I was using that. Since the data only changes in the controller, never in my directive, I suspected the @ was sufficient enough. But appearently, it works differently then I thought.

Comment: @Cornelis You are welcome. Well you can use `@` but as i mentioned in the answer you need to do it in a different way.